# Account banned from asking questions despite being compliant with rules?

Tags: support, post-ban

I've asked five questions on Stack Overflow, and all of them are in compliance with the [FAQ on the question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998).

What was the purpose of my ban?  You guys tell me, because I'm clueless. Check [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392628/eric-leroy?tab=questions). I can't be described by any of the following:

> - users who can't be bothered to form sentences
> - users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves
> - users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do

Comment: Did you delete any of your questions?

Comment: Nope. If so, maybe one, but nothing recent. The only thing I can think of is I was clicking refresh on the reviews to try to catch the next batch. Maybe it kicked me because it thought I was a bot?

Comment: How can I find out who banned me and for what?

Comment: The ban is automatic and the exact algorithm is not disclosed. I've quickly checked your visible questions and they look decent, if not good, perhaps this is a false positive. Are you sharing your IP?

Comment: 7 questions, 2 closed, 2 deleted. 2 raised flags on your questions. Very few (exactly one) upvotes on your questions. I suggest inviting other users to see if your remaining non-deleted questions are worthy of upvotes.

Comment: One of the closures is actually a migration to SU, and a borderline one in my opinion, @JeffAtwood. It's about software installation, yes, but dev tool installation. "How to install the compiler the platform vendor uses, without the rest of the vendor's IDE package?" is a question about tools specific to programmers.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Only because he used a damn fool link shortner thingy, no one could tell. That's his own fault.

Comment: @dmckee No, that's how the message is displayed to users, the damn fool link shortner thingy is Stack Exchange's fault.

Comment: Yeah, so somebody fix this please.  I'm not posting bad questions, And nobody has a clear answer to what exact cause was.  Why would I continue answer all these questions for people when I can't ask questions when I need help?

Comment: @EricLeroy Jeff gave you an answer, more than half of your questions have been closed and/or deleted (1 closed, 1 migrated, 2 deleted out of 7 total). That's... not good.

Comment: In fact, I **do** think your questions are rather poor. For example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312691/) asks multiple questions, is really broad and would come close to closure IMHO. And I would have also voted to close your latest closed question.

Comment: Half of seven?  Wow.  3 and half of my Very First Questions where bad.

Comment: You know what. There are people with 50+ up votes on a multiple question answer.

Comment: And that latest closed question has upvotes on SuperUser it was migrated

Comment: If you want us to tell you that all is peachy and fine, don't ask for our explanation. We're trying to help here.

Comment: I understand, and that closed wasn't migrated, that one asked if scroll was a css property for IE.  What's so wrong with that? I couldn't find any documentation we had a discussion about it on a different post, so I asked it to solve the problem.

Comment: Meh. This is an individual capable of doing advanced level stuff; I'm going with the benefit of the doubt here and upvoting what I think is useful. For future reference, when asking, just try to conform to the SO Q&A model a bit more: make sure you ask one very specific question per question. That'll probably also get you better responses on the Google maps one.

Comment: Somebody have management fix it. Just drop them a message or something. I"m not going to bother helping contribute anymore if they're going to block me from asking but let me answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this can't be just "fixed". It's an algorithm that is applied to everybody equally. So the only way to get unbanned is to get you back across the threshold. They won't "change" the algorithm for just one person. That said, all you probably need are a few upvotes.

Comment: @Eric Dude, you are *talking* to management among others. And you are mostly wrong: this tool is badly needed. Your case *might* indicate that it could use a *little* tweaking, but that's all.

Comment: "Somebody have management fix it"--I know it's frustrating, but good contributions are a two-way street. Don't expect the site to conform to exactly how you've been asking questions.

Comment: @Pekka okay, but then I can also get closed for asking too specific questions?  It's like there should be at least 10 model questions that are great formats, so people can understand.  I've read the faqs.  I am a visual learner. I need examples of good questions, because in my mind, I've got better questions asked than half  of the people I've helped in the past week.

Comment: @Eric yeah, I tend to agree with your last sentence. Re examples, one approach might be checking out the tags you want to ask in (like `google-maps`) and looking at the highly upvoted questions in there. It's not a guarantee you will find the best questions in regards to the SO "ideal" (voting is sometimes somewhat arbitrary), but you should find some examples of what makes a good SO question.

Comment: @dmckee yes. The algorithm needs to be adjusted, I agree. I'm not saying get rid of it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but given Jeff's summary (7 questions, 2 closed, 2 deleted, 2 flags) the algorithm does not need to be adjusted. You can argue about the validity of those decisions, but in terms of the automatic ban you have the numbers against you.

Comment: Honestly, I pulled 235 points yesterday for helping people.  That algorithm took someone that got highly addicted to spending hours learning and helping other, and in return, said keep helping, but you can't be helped. If management is in here, past this to your superiors please. I want to be able to ask questions, or I'm done helping others.

Comment: @EricLeroy `If management is in here, past this to your superiors please` Fifth comment from the top in this thread is by someone with a diamond next to their name, check out his profile. His user ID is also revealing ;)

Comment: Cool so Jeff doesn't want to do anything about it fine. My loss right?

Comment: @Eric: Jeff is no longer a SE employee.  So what he wants to do about it means about as much as what the rest of us want to do about it.  :)

Comment: @EricLeroy No, not really, that's not how it works (and Jeff's retired). But I must say the time & energy you're spending here would be much better spent in improving your open questions and your answers (only 17 of your 51 answers have a positive score), even if you feel the ban is unfair.

Comment: Some votes on your existing questions could solve your problem, and @Perka indicated a willingness to help with that. I went to have a look for myself and see if I could do the same. Take [the one I feel most able to comment on](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12831791): you never used a phrase like *"I'd like to be able to select based on just the hours part of the time stamp"*. One sentence like that would render the question enormously clearer. The trick is always to make the question clear to someone who has not been thinking about it for `$LONGTIME` already, which can take some care.

Comment: So I obviously do belong around all the perfect people. I'm going to go now.

Comment: Oh come on. Don't whine. You've been given some comments on what to address. Spend some energy on improving what you have contributed so far (gaining some upvotes in the process) and you should be just fine. Avoid any further closures and you should never run into this problem again.

Comment: Based on your very positive and receptive attitude I'm sure you will be greatly missed.

Comment: @EricLeroy  Your basically pulling in sympathy upvotes and yet you're still complaining.

Comment: I'm not pulling in sympathy. Just realization on the topic that happened back then

Answer (score 21):

(Preamble: I'm a community manager at Stack Exchange, so you can consider this a response from the management. :))

As mentioned in the comments, this question asking block is fully automatic. There is no person in this company who can click a button to lift it because there is no such button.

The meta FAQ post describes some of the behaviours that are likely to lead to a block, but they're not intended to be fully comprehensive or a judgement on your programming abilities.

The overall intention of this block is to ask that you work on your **existing** content before trying to post further. The voting on your content is a measurement of how much the community finds it worthwhile, so if you can improve your existing questions enough to get them up-voted, your ability to post again will be reinstated automatically by the system.

With that said, it looks like this meta post has had its ultimately desired effect and you are no longer blocked from posting questions. I suggest keeping the general tips from [the meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998) as well as the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) in mind when asking future questions. They should help you write questions that attract attention and upvotes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So no button to lift but you can see how close a user is to get banned or get out of a ban? That's quite useful as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Moderators and diamonded employees can see who is blocked and whether or not they actually encountered the block if they are. (It's basically an at-post-time check, so it's possible for a user to be blocked from asking or answering and not know it if they haven't attempted to make a post). Moderators don't have access to the exact formula.

Comment: *There is no person in this company who can click a button to lift it because there is no such button.* Excuse me? You guys at SE write the software that runs this website. You can do whatever you want with it, including commenting out the whole autoban code. It's your deliberate choice to ban accounts with low score; stop using the old "the computer won't let me do it" excuse.