# Work is hard, let's color the walls

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013, fun

Picture pages! Picture pages! Time to get your [picture pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Pages)!

... ***[time to get your crayons and your pencils!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qgBjoL_auM)***

That's right, it's time to realize that you're simply *not* going to get anything meaningful accomplished this week, and your time would be better rewarded by joining in on the last of three end-of-the-year mini-contests for Stack Overflow swag!

#### The final challenge:

*Create an original hand drawn illustration of any Stack Exchange community, or a depiction of participating in any Stack Exchange community*. You can use Paint, Photoshop or real crayons and paper, the only requirement is that the finished product ***must be free hand***, and ***must be under 5MB in size***. You may use small existing elements (a tag, icon, etc) - the *overwhelming majority* of your entry should be drawn by you.

You're free to incorporate any related elements into your drawing, such as (but not limited to):

- Unicorns
- One-armed dragons
- Ponies
- Mythical lords of the abyss
- ... anything else that you'd like

Your final product should be easy enough to view directly within your answer; the image should link directly to the larger version if applicable.

Submissions must begin with a title of up to 60 characters that (at a minimum) states the community that inspired your work (e.g. Stack Overflow), more creativity is strongly encouraged in the title (e.g *The night before ponies — Stack Overflow*)

One paragraph (350 chars or less) is permitted to provide context below your image, and may contain inline links to explain any memes depicted.

A good example is [this awesome mural by Pekka](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121722/50049), which inspired this contest.

#### The grand prize:

The top three entries as determined by net up-vote counts will win the following items:

- Stack Overflow T-Shirt
- Stack Overflow Mug
- A Stack Overflow padfolio, for future doodling endeavors
- Pens (3), retractable sharpies (2), stickers (assortment of 10)

Two runners-up will receive a Stack Overflow T-Shirt and an assortment of stickers.

#### The rules:

- Entry must be your own original work, created on or after December 26, 2013
- No more than two entries per person (deleted entries do not count)
- Changing the image after the initial edit grace period is prohibited and will disqualify the entry, but editing the title or paragraph is allowed.
- Employees are welcome to participate, but aren't eligible to win prizes. Y'all can get this stuff on request and your entry might knock a community entry out of the running
- A tie for a winning entry causes each entry with the same score to win
- Score is determined by total upvotes received, downvotes do not count.
- Entries must be received by Monday, December 30, 2013 at 16:00 UTC

***Now get started!***

*Note: please make sure you have a working email that you actually check rather frequently associated with your account if you enter, this ensures that all prizes can be awarded quickly. Thanks!*

---

#### And the winners are ....

***Grand Prize***

- [Unicorn Dollars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213830) by [Pëkka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138112) (Score 60)
- [How to cause an apocalypse, or, Atlas visits Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213798) by [Mr. Peanut Monopoly McManish](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178438) (Score 30)
- [The Guardian Unicorn Of Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213782) by [Undo The Snowman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215468) (Score 21)
- [More Please!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213857) by [ChristopherW](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215556) (Also score 21)

***Runners Up***

- [Lounge<C++> the best, the funniest, the coolest SO chatroom in teh worldz!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213781) by [BartoszKP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/231717) (Score 20)
- [Stack Overflow - Professionals at work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213802) by [juergen d](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172011) (Score 18)

You'll get an email from me with a link to a form where you can provide your size and shipping information, I plan on shipping this stuff before the end of the week.

Thank you, again, to everyone that made this contest as fun as it was. We've now got some *awesome* artwork to decorate the meta halls in 2014!

P.S. - If you enjoyed, or absolutely *hated* these contests, please reach out to me and let me know, my email address is in my profile. This year was a test to see how well they would be received *and* contained, and I think it went pretty well. We'll have time to put more thought into them next year, and come up with more creative ideas for things we could do. Still - feedback is appreciated, even if you can't muster much more than *get off my lawn*.

***Happy New Year To All!***

Comment: Arrrghh. The temptation!

Comment: Why is this tagged winter bash? Can't see any reference to hats.. ?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Because it's something were doing in conjunction with Winter Bash.

Comment: @Tim fair enough... so adding hats is fine too, right?

Comment: regarding: "must be free-hand" - can some small non free-hand elements be incorporated? like badge or tag sprites? or rendered text?

Comment: @BartoszKP I implied that we could. If I were to draw one of those hats, no one would understand what it is.

Comment: @Pëkka, if temptation alone is not enough: I happen to know you can draw very nicely...!

Comment: @Arjan thank you! :) But I want to get some of my own drawing done, hence this is an evil temptation.

Comment: But wouldn't you need some shiny new retractable sharpies for that, @Pëkka? ;-) (I had to use Google image search to know what those are.)

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname I agree. But nevertheless, because of no official statement I've rendered my fonts by hand ;)

Comment: Alternatively, @Pëkka, change the company name [in this](http://pgaiser.net/drawing/craigslist-application/) and become part of *"Y'all can get this stuff on request"* ;-)

Comment: @Arjan lol -----

Comment: @BartoszKP Yes, I updated the post to reflect that. An icon or a tag is fine. A picture of a unicorn isn't (draw the unicorn instead) - for example.

Comment: What was the second contest? (Assuming [Should employees with head injuries be allowed to post on meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212433/1288) was the first.)

Comment: Already posted my two entries, so I'll post more in comments because I'm bored. [The land of the free(hand)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uABpW.png)

Comment: One more: [Weapons of mass destructions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/akaQw.png)

Comment: @Bill, maybe [I would like a mug please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208393/i-would-like-a-mug-please), in which Tiny Tim also offered mugs?

Comment: @Arjan Ah, you're probably right. I had forgotten about that.

Comment: Looks like people totally ignore the "downvotes do not count" part and wasting downvotes here... no way to lock downvotes?

Comment: @sha we could carry out the competition in t he comments :p

Comment: You mention that entries must be in by the 30th. Does voting close then as well?

Comment: @RichardTingle If we take the other competitions as precedent, they lock the post. Pekka deserves a gold 100 votes badge for his answer, though. Hopefully he gets it before the lock :)

Comment: I would love to participate, but (sigh) my drawing is as bad as (no comments :P)

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, at 16:00 UTC today (or, in approximately two hours) this post will be locked, the scores tallied using a query and the winners announced.

Comment: @TinyTim Ah, I had assumed it would be entries closed, then a voting period, then over. Ah well, live and learn

Answer (score 59):

Unicorn Dollars!

[image]

With the most sincere apologies to Jeff and Joel. I'm just getting started drawing faces.

Comment: I wondered when you'll show up! ;)

Comment: Bummer. No umlaut!

Comment: wow! really nice!

Comment: I want real money to look like this.

Comment: Suggestion (not that you can really change it now): Change `THE UNITED STATES OF STACK EXCHANGE` to `THE UNITED SITES OF STACK EXCHANGE`.

Comment: @Undo great idea! I may do a correction round later, also to make the small latin text more readable

Comment: Yeah, us sites are *sooo* united... */sarcasm* Still, I think it would sound better that way.

Comment: @Seth well, as united as these United States :)

Comment: How cool would a Stack Exchange inspired currency be? You are only profitable based upon the knowledge you give in a broad variety of topics.

Comment: I expect tens of thousands of these to show up in a duffel bag when they are produced.

Comment: I don't see what significance, if any, 187606 has.  If it does not have any particular significance, consider changing it to 1732348 when you create the official Stack Exchange Reputation Currency.

Comment: @Adam that number was avoided in the production process, just as there is no 13th floor in many highrises.

Comment: Oh my God, PEKKA CAN NOW PRINT REP. This can only end in disaster, as people rush the reputation banks in a mad frenzy!

Comment: @TinyTim there was a series of forgeries in 2009-10 where the notes said "ONE EXP". The culprit was apprehended quickly.

Comment: Damn... This shuold be printed and delivered as a gift next christmas!

Comment: Shut up and take my rep!!

Comment: Looking at this again, I think you might have just created Keanu Spolsky.

Answer (score 28):

### How to cause an apocalypse, or, Atlas visits Stack Overflow

[image]

[Background meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/178438), [Who Atlas is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_%28mythology%29). The other head is [Ólafur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22459/olafur-waage)

Comment: Unfortunately I suck at drawing beards. Scratch that, I suck at drawing. I should totally drop drawing and try jQuery.

Comment: Painfully accurate

Answer (score 18):

### More Please!

If I ever stop using Stack Exchange/Overflow, at least I will remember to never use the deprecated `mysql` PHP libraries and that jQuery is better than everything...even if my question was about Powershell.

[jQuery reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/215556)

[image: More please]

Comment: see the red box in the manual...lol `mysql`

Comment: Hahaha, this is awesome.

Comment: `even if my question was about Powershell.` LOL

Comment: -1, the Freehand Circle isn't Red. (jk)

Comment: I didn't want him to be a red head :-(

Answer (score 17):

#### Stack Overflow - Professionals at work

[image: Professionals]

Answer (score 16):

#### The guardian unicorn of Meta Stack Overflow

[image]

We need one of these.

Comment: I am proud to be a Unicorn.

Comment: This is beautiful. We *all* are guardian unicorns occasionally.

Answer (score 15):

[Lounge<C++>](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) the best, the funniest, the coolest SO chatroom in teh worldz!

[image]

Top text is one of past top-starred [messages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=13172730#13172730). The bottoms "tags" are exemplary tags that were/are in the room's description.

Dedicated to nice people I met there and spend some good time with (alphabetically): Abyx, Bartek Banachewicz, Borgleader, Cat Plus Plus, DeadMG, Ell, Etienne de Martel, FredOverflow, Games Brainiac, Jefffrey, Jerry Coffin, Lightness Races in Orbit, Martin James, melak47, Mohammad Ali Baydoun , Mysticial, Pawnguy7, R. Martinho Fernandes, Rapptz, rightfold, ScottW, sehe, StackedCrooked, ThePhD, Tony The Lion, Xeo, and others (sorry for not remembering everyone!).

Comment: The worst part about this is that it's mostly accurate :P

Comment: The best part is no Oztralians in the list:)

Comment: I like how the "why doesn't work?" guy  has the classic thinker's pose.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Phew... My name isn't there. There's some other guy name "Mystical", never heard of him. *whistles...*

Comment: @Mysticial lol, `@` should work with first letters in posts also ;0 btw. haven't you considered changing your nickname?

Comment: Dammit, you "fixed" it. :(:(:(

Comment: @Mysticial That's my primal instinct for bug fixing. But feel free to edit it to whatever you like :D

Comment: You remembered me ;_;
I love you ;_; (Needs more Java and PHP hate though)

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun I considered that! But I decided to be politically correct. I'm weak, I know.

Answer (score 14):

**JavaScript != Java**

[image]

Comment: Well, I did tell you I was *new* to it. Tsk. Some people...

Answer (score 9):

StackOverflow evolution

[image]

Answer (score 9):

#### Getting out of Stack Overflow question ban

[image]

Sometimes [it's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212380/on-question-bans#comment683403_212380) [possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151452/152859).

Comment: You know, I felt reminded of http://img.chan4chan.com/img/2009-03-31/bunnylove.jpg

Comment: @Pëkka awesome, you made my night! (2:30 AM here so will go to bed with a smile :-))

Comment: @Pëkka incidentally, originally from the Perry Bible Fellowship.  [#77 - Bunny Pit](http://pbfcomics.com/77/).  If you like that one, you may find the rest of pbf amusing. Warning, not all are safe for work viewing.

Comment: @Michael nice! Very funny stuff.

Comment: @Pëkka From PBF, I'm not sure if [nice shirt](http://pbfcomics.com/103/) or [the last unicorns](http://pbfcomics.com/253/) is more appropriate for MSO.

Answer (score 8):

## If you only knew the horror outside - Stack Overflow

[image]

The moderation of stack overflow; both community and diamond moderator. Despite what [some may say](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213769/work-is-hard-lets-color-the-walls/214051#comment689576_214051) the pile of earth is a spammer tunnelling under the community moderation and being stopped by a mod.

Comment: Why is the moderator buying viagra from a pile of poop?

Comment: Its supposed to be a spammer tunnelling under the community moderation (see the spade) and the moderator holding up a detectives badge basically saying "banned"

Comment: I like my version better :P

Comment: I like us being evil, authoritarian riot cops.

Comment: Since when is Slenderman a mod?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar *looks up slenderman*, ha! That really does look like slenderman! But sadly it is actually a symptom of my inability to draw faces

Answer (score 6):

**Ẃ̱̜̩̞͎̜͇̂͗̑ͪ̈I͙̬̺̼̲͍ͣ̔̎ͩ̈̾͟ͅN͓̎̌ͦ͆T̤̮̮̣̘̞̓̎͞Ẻ̪̀̆͋͌̔R̥̣̫͍͈̓ ͉͕ͤ̒ͦI̗̊̂ͭͤ̐̀̿̀S͎͉͙͑̽́̎ͫ̐ͦ ͇̯͍̹̥̫͚̓͘C̟̩Ǒ̎͊͑̃ͅM̖̳̠͉ͩ͐ͪI̸̗ͬͣN̸̖̺̜̘͙̟͖̊͌G̮̟̟̟̝͉ͨ̈ͣ̉̃͌͐̕**

[image]

Comment: Implied I could use *some* non-freehand elements.

Answer (score 6):

**Extinction**: *Act Now*, or Forever Hold Your Peace

[image]

<sub>someone had to [represent](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/)...</sub>

Answer (score 6):

### Users participating in the `C` tag watch a unicorn dying because a new fella casts the return value of `malloc()`.

[image]

Comment: ... all these years ... I ... I never knew. I'm a _horrible_ programmer.

Comment: @TinyTim Don't worry, tiny Tim, it's over now. It's gonna be all right. :-)

Comment: Love the baseball hat.

Comment: @KerrekSB Since it's winter time, I thought some sort of hat would be a good idea. (Also, I hope everyone groks the reference to Unwind.)

Answer (score 6):

### Stack Overflow - even your girlfriend knows it

[image: vacation]

Comment: This has never happened to me. *shifty eyes*. On an unrelated note; ferrys in the middle of the the sea have wifi too these days

Comment: I once went on vacation for a few days just when the 100 days had almost been reached.  I tried to access the sites via mobile, but one day it wasn't possible so I lost out that time.

Comment: Nobody is wondering what codinghorror is doing with @juergen d's girlfriend?

Answer (score 4):

### Internet? You should totally drop that and try Amateur Radio

[image: Internet? You should totally drop that and try CW. Ham.stackexchange.com. Image of unicorn operating morse code key connected to transmitter and antenna.]

Answer (score 3):

## Wait, wait... I know the answer! - Stack Overflow

[image]

Sometimes, you just want to pause SO to counteract [the fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533/162538). *(Or get it fueled by, actually, possibly.)*

Answer (score 3):

(This is very *Meta* Meta)

### All Over the SE Network - [Dont Wake *The Shog*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1C17ZQHAthw)

When a fight or flame rises, [***The Shog***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/9-shogs-a-shogging) arises.

[image: Dont Wake The Shog]

> In case you didnt get it:
>  
> Panel 1: Flame starts on MSO
>  
> Panel 2: Fight ensues (middle of the panel). Shog passes by.
>  
> Panel 3: Shog attempts to calm/mediate.
>  
> Panel 4: Fight continues
>  
> Panel 5: Shog gets angry
>  
> Panel 6: *The Shog Awakens.*

<sub>Some details not visible. See [high-res image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIXxo.jpg).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

### **How to burninate (*hat edition*)**

[image]

[Background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101417/241700)

Comment: I cannot draw Trogdor well...

Answer (score 2):

### The Meta Effect

[image]

Inspired by a by [my favorite xkcd](http://xkcd.com/386/), and my patient yet irritated wife...

Answer (score 1):

Paranoia in late answers to old questions

[image]

Comment: BUT I WAS ONLY TRYING TO HELP

Answer (score 0):

TONY THE PONY, HE COMES

[image]

---

References:

- The timeless post by [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1026459
- Unicorns (self-evident)
- Jon Skeet's Tony the Pony hand puppet https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/
- The apparent endless supply of html regex questions
- Free-hand drawn red circles

Answer (score -2):

### Eternity (Meta Stack Overflow)

[image]

[Background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/178438)

Answer (score -2):

### Only my name is enough : Jon Skeet

[image: jon skeet]

Answer (score -11):

#### Stack Overflow Deity

[image]

Simply the best. ©

Comment: As a caricature this is hilarious